# Failing to grant select on a specific schema's table in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want a user I have created in `redshift` to have only `SELECT` grant on a specific table (`mytable`) of a specific schema (`myschema`).

I have already created the user `myser`, however the following command fails:

```
mydb=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mytable IN SCHEMA "myschema" TO myuser;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IN"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE "myschema".mytable to myuser;
```

Answer (score 0):

The concern here is that you cannot use this syntax. According to the documentation, you have the following:

```
ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...] | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
```

This means that, if you want to specify a table name, you can't use the `IN SCHEMA` syntax. You'll need to prefix your table name with the correct schema name. In this case, you would do as Julia Leder pointed out: `ON TABLE "myschema".mytable`.